# Why is Paypal displaying SUCCESS and $_POST variables Paypal's site instead of returning to my return_url

Tags: php, paypal

Please help me.  I'm at a total loss.  After more than 2 days of Googling everything I can think of, I still have no answers.  This DID work in the Sandbox.  My code for sending the tx and token to Paypal.

```
<form name='verification' action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='at' value='$atoken' />
    <input type='hidden' name='tx' value='$tx' />
    <input type='hidden' name='rm' value='2' />
    <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_notify-synch' />");
    print("<input type='hidden' name='return' value='$returnUrl' />");
    print("<input type='submit' name='submit' value='PDT'>");
print("</form>");
```

Comment: I was able to find some curl script that makes this work, although I still wish I knew why my original code wouldn't work.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The variable for return url is `return_url` not `return`. It should also be an account in your Paypal account.

Comment: I changed the return variable to return_url as you suggested, but I still get the same result.  Do you have any other suggestions?  I am at a total loss.

Comment: @user3133140 whatever is starting the transaction should be sending the return_url, you can also set it up in your account settings.

Answer (score 0):

your amount and tax variables are not being parsed

```
<input type='hidden' name='at' value='<?=$atoken?>' />
<input type='hidden' name='tx' value='<?=$tx?>' />
```

Comment: I actually have the values hardcoded in, but didn't want to send the values for everyone to see.  Do you have any other suggestions I can try?  EVERYTHING is working except that Paypal posts the information to a blank page on their own site.